# Slurm server with a asterisk near the "idle"

Tags: slurm

I'm using Slurm. When I run

> sinfo -Nel

it is common to see a server designated as `idle`, but sometimes there is also a little asterisk near it (Like this: `idle*`).

What does that mean? I couldn't find any info about that. (The server is up and running).

Comment: Well, It looks like there was a problem with the slurm deamon on that server. I have restarted it on the server and the asterisk was gone. The slurm log on the server is empty so I don't know why that was happen.

Comment: Yes thanks, `sudo service slurmd restart` on the affected node fixed it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When an `*` appears after the state of a node it means that the node is unreachable

Quoting the sinfo manpage under the `NODE STATE CODES` section:

> *   The node is presently not responding and will not be allocated any new work.  If the node remains non-responsive, it will be placed in the DOWN state (except in the case of COMPLETING, DRAINED, DRAINING, FAIL, FAILING
>              nodes).

Comment: Ok, I wanted to ask why its not mark as "down" but I thought that just like my case, He wan't "down", its just that the slurm deamon wasn't working.

Comment: Great, The info you added after editing was just what I wanted to know. The nood wiil switch to "Down" state after a while. Thanks.